# Crash when loading main xib on iPad only in universal app?

Tags: ios, ipad, xib, universal

I have a universal app but this issue seems to only relate to the iPad and not the iPhone since the iPhone version loads the correct XIB.

So pretty much the issue is, it is not loading my main XIB for my app. ***I named the XIB's like so:***

1. For iPhone: MyViewController.xib

   1. For iPad: MyViewController_iPad.xib

Also I deleted my MainWindow.xib because in the template project for a universal app it shows no MainWindow.xib anywhere.

This is how I am trying to load the view on app launch:

```
self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        self.viewController = [[[ocrapiViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    } else {
        self.viewController = [[[ocrapiViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyViewController_iPad" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    }
 self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
```

**This is the crash info:**
A SIGABRT on this line `[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];`

And this is the crash log:

```
2011-12-07 07:37:46.560 ocrapi[763:607] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </var/mobile/Applications/29F4CD7A-149E-46EA-B280-3D188PP19D17/.app> (loaded)' with name 'MyViewController_iPad''
```

**Edit1**:
Here is the message:

```
warning: No copy of <No file name> found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
```

Also if I click on my products then do show in finder, then do show package contents, MyViewController.xib or MyViewController_iPad.xib is not there. Is it supposed to be like that?

Comment: when you assign `self.window.rootViewController`, check and see if `self.viewController` is not null.

Comment: no it is not NULL I just NSLogged it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your nib really really really is called MyViewController_iPad.xib, with that exact capitalization.

Make sure the xib file is in your target's list of things to be copied to the app on build.

Finally, make sure you've no Main Nib setting still in your Info.plist file.

Oh, and one more thing. There is no need for this code:

```
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
    self.viewController = [[[ocrapiViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
} else {
    self.viewController = [[[ocrapiViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyViewController_iPad" bundle:nil] autorelease];
}
```

Simply call `initWithNibName:@"MyViewController"`. If your iPad nib is named *MyViewController~ipad.xib* (note the twiddle, note the lowercase "ipad") it will be chosen automatically when you're on an iPad.

Comment: You mean if I click the project then go to build phases? It was not in there before but I added it. There is no crash now but it still doesn't load the view. Look at my edit1 for a new message the console says when it tries to load the view.

Comment: If you're really having trouble tracking this down, I'd suggest you drop back ten yards and punt: Start all over with a new project made direct from an Xcode 4.2 template.

Comment: Alright I will try your edited answer first later on. My project is just so big so I would rather not making a whole new project.

Comment: Start small. After all, right now all you need to do is convince yourself that you can show some initial interface!

Comment: I fixed it! It happened to be a lingering setting in my info.plist :/ Im not even sure how it was still there after Im sure I deleted it.

Comment: Well done! The Info.plist editor is by no means a good interface. It really helps to look at the file in xml (Open As Source in the contextual menu) - I wouldn't try to edit it like that, as you can shoot yourself in the foot and have the thing go bad with no warning message, but at least you can see what's really going on.